# Correctly routing incoming sms with shared number twilio

Tags: web-applications, sms, twilio

> Scenario:  Webapp has 100 Admin users and 10000 users.
>
> Admin users can send all users sms messages from the webapp.
>
> the users can send sms back to admins from their phone.

My question is if new Admin users are being created on the fly. How can I route the incoming sms message from user to the correct admin who sent the message. Is it possible to use a single number to send all messages from all Admins and then somehow filter and match and route to the correct admin. Or is the only way to do this by purchasing multiple numbers ahead of time and then assign each new admin a unique number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There is no functionality in SMS for replying to certain messages (take a look at your SMS app on your phone, there is no reply-to functionality).

So, the only way to route replies to different admins is for each admin to use a different number.

You wouldn't necessarily have to buy all the numbers up front, you can use the Twilio REST API to [search for](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/available-phone-numbers) and [buy phone numbers](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/incoming-phone-numbers#list-post) on the fly as admins need a number or are created.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: greta, purchasing of numbers on the fly will suffice for my case. I wasn't sure that was possible.